# Does white balance correction improve the performance of visual object detection?

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition, image-preprocessing, image

Visual object detecion aims to locate and recognize objects of interest in images.

I wonder, does white balance correction contribute to better performance of visual object detection? Are there any related studies or papers?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any papers, though making your objects more distinct should definitely help your model to learn proper filters. One thing to keep in mind though is your production data. Will you be also feeding images with poor exposure, white balance, contrast? If so, you need to train your model on such data. As far as I know, [this repository](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) produces by far most possible augmentations to images.